# Getting No FileSystem for Schema WASB . Hdinsight Map Reduce

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, reduce, azure-hdinsight

I am running a simple map reduce job in Azure HDInsight,below is the command that we are running:

```
java -jar WordCount201.jar wasb://hexhadoopcluster-2019-05-15t07-01-07-193z@hexanikahdinsight.blob.core.windows.net/hexa/CustData.csv wasb://hexhadoopcluster-2019-05-15t07-01-07-193z@hexanikahdinsight.blob.core.windows.net/hexa
```

Getting the below error :

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasb
```

Comment: For Java use jdk1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hadoop job kindly run the jar from root user . Once you login to HDinsight run the command sudo su - . And the create a folder and place the jar to that folder and run the jar .

Answer (score 0):

For Java use jdk1.8  and below POM org.apache.hadoop hadoop-mapreduce-examples2.7.3scope>provided  org.apache.hadoophadoop-mapreduce-client-common2.7.3providedjdk.toolsjdk.toolsorg.apache.hadoophadoop-common2.7.3provided

Comment: This is the correct answer? If no, please edit your question and add there the new information, not here.

Answer (score 0):

WASB is a wrapper around HDFS file system. I am not sure you can use it in normal java program. Do you have any reference / link which you referred to?

You can try to get the https equivalent of the custData.csv file.Below is an example of Spark job I am able to submit on HDInsight cluster using WASB

```sh
spark-submit \
--class com.nileshgule.movielens.MovieRatingAnalysis \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--executor-memory 1g \
--name MoviesCsvReader \
--conf "spark.app.id=MovieRatingAnalysis" \
wasb://hd-spark-cluster-2019@hdsparkclusterstorage.blob.core.windows.net/learning-spark-1.0.jar \
wasb://hd-spark-cluster-2019@hdsparkclusterstorage.blob.core.windows.net/ml-latest/ratings.csv \
wasb://hd-spark-cluster-2019@hdsparkclusterstorage.blob.core.windows.net/ml-latest/movies.csv
```

And here is an example of passing the same files using their equivalent https URI

```sh
spark-submit \
--class com.nileshgule.movielens.MovieRatingAnalysis \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--executor-memory 1g \
--name MoviesCsvReader \
--conf "spark.app.id=MovieRatingAnalysis" \
https://hdsparkclusterstorage.blob.core.windows.net/hd-spark-cluster-2019/learning-spark-1.0.jar \
https://hdsparkclusterstorage.blob.core.windows.net/hd-spark-cluster-2019/ml-latest/ratings.csv \
https://hdsparkclusterstorage.blob.core.windows.net/hd-spark-cluster-2019/ml-latest/movies.csv
```